# Consistent graceful disconnect from Bluetooth server when receiving BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_OFF

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am having trouble disconnecting gracefully from a server when the user turns off the bluetooth. Android generates an event when that happens that you are supposed to use to send a final disconnection message to the server; before your app loses access to bluetooth functionality.

I register the event like this:

```
context.registerReceiver(this, new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED));
```

Then I listen for the specific event:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    final int state = 
        intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE, BluetoothAdapter.ERROR);
    switch (state) {
        case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_OFF: 
             _bt.stop(); 
             break;
        //...
    }
}
```

This works some times but not every time. I tried giving the thread a higher priority to see if it would help with (alternatively) both of these:

```
Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_URGENT_DISPLAY);
```

... but no luck. Any ideas on how to accomplish this consistently are welcome, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So, what ended up working for me is to use both priority statements and try to send the message as soon as the event is generated. This way, I consistently get a graceful disconnection from the server. This is how my code ended up looking:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
    android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_URGENT_DISPLAY);
    final int state = 
        intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE, BluetoothAdapter.ERROR);
    switch (state) {
        case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_OFF: 
            // send disconnection message
            _bt.stop(); 
            break;
        //...
    }
}
```

Hope it helps someone else.